# How to update the firmware of HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw?

Tags: windows, security, printer, firmware

How can I update the firmware of my printer HP LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw?
(this is important because of [security issues](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c07058567))

The printer is installed on Windows, and HP Smart is installed and communicates with the printer.

I found the firmware install for Windows here:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-mfp-m125-series/5396664

But when I launch the program, it doesn't detect my printer.

The steps provided on the HP web site don't work. HP virtual agent didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Connect the printer to a Windows computer directly via an **USB cable**. You can't upgrade via network.
2. If, when you connect the printer, a new CD drive called "Smart Install" appears in the explorer, you must **disable the "Smart Install" feature** in the configuration menus on the printer (Englsh/French).

   1. "Setup Menu Service" / "Menu config Service"
   2. "Service Smart Install" / "Service Installation Intelligente HP"
   3. "Off" / "Désactivée"
3. Disconnect & reconnect the USB cable
4. Download the latest firmware upgrade tool (HP_M125_126_FW_Update_20201012.exe) from: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-mfp-m125-series/5396664
5. Launch the firmware upgrade